ssh to instance on Private Subnet through instance on Public Subnet within the same VPC
I have two subnets in one VPC (say "My VPC"):

Public Subnet- connected to Internet Gateway through route table 0.0.0.0/0. I can connect to an instance named Public Instance on this Subnet from my local machine using pem file and MobaXterm. This Public subnet is also having another default route table associated with the VPC - My VPC
Private Subnet- It is having only one Route Table which is associated with My VPC. I have one instance running on this Private subnet, named as say Private Instance.

I am trying to ssh to this Private Instance from my Public Instance as these two are in same VPC. I have copied the key pair for "Private Instance" to the "Public Instance" and trying to use ssh command while I have logged in to "Public Instance" through MobaXterm.
This image shows the setup I have in AWS:

I can connect to the Private Instance from my local machine (Laptop) using Mobaxterm.
But I can not do ssh from Public Instance to Private Instance, although they are in same VPC. The request gets timed out.
I have copied the keypair of Private instance to Public Instance from where I am trying to do the ssh.
I am expecting to connect to the Private Instance through Public instance.
Thank you for your help.

You need to attach a Security Group to the private instance that permits access from the Public Instance.
The preferred configuration is:

A Security Group on the Public instance (SG-Public) that grants Inbound access for SSH (port 22) from 0.0.0.0/0 and permits All Outbound access
A Security Group on the Private instance (SG-Private) that grants Inbound access for SSH from SG-Public) and permits All Outbound access

That is, SG-Private should specifically reference SG-Public. This way, any instance associated with the SG-Public security group will be able to SSH into any instance associated with the SG-Private security group.
Please note that putting both instances "into the same security group" is not always sufficient because the security groups are applied to instances individually.

Hi , Actually I have the SG in place, for Public Instance, inbound  SSH access is there from 0.0.0.0/0 and outbound traffic is open for all . For Private instance also, I do have a different SG with SSH access for 0.0.0.0/0 and now I have added the PublicSG as weel , although I think if SSH is enabled for 0.0.0.0/0 it was no more required with all outbound traffic enabled. Still I see the same issue.

Have you modified the Network ACLs at all? They should generally be left alone with their default "Allow All" setting. Can you show us the SSH command you are using (the one that hangs)?
